# android: turn screen Off

Tags: android, screen

Purpose :

> in an android app, turn screen off when user touch a button.

Answers already exist :

1. Set screen brightness to zero.

   ```
   WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes(); 
   params.flags |= LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON; 
   params.screenBrightness = 0; 
   getWindow().setAttributes(params);
   ```

   > This code makes screen dim, but can't turn off.
2. Use PowerManager.WakeLock

   ```
   PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
   PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "My Tag");
   wl.acquire();
   //..screen will stay on during this section..
   //wl.release();
   ```

   > This code keep a phone at 'Wake_State'. In following [Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXJ5k.png),
   >   'PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK' looks to turn off screen. But it just allows that a user turn screen off personally (maybe with power-button).

So, I want to turn screen fully off not using 'power-button'. Thanks for reading.

**--- Add about my intention -------------------------**

My user needs to turn screen off while other apps are keep working. Not to make 'POWER_KEY_DOWN(UP)_EVENT' I chose this way. I welcome another way which archive same purpose.

Comment: this sounds like virus similar app. turning off the screen on display touch will annoy Your users....

Comment: Maybe on rooted devices.

Comment: @Opiatefuchs I wrote little more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it by setting the wake_setting time to 1 second.

I have already tried both of above shared ways, which shows slightly visible screen on but by setting wake_setting to 1 sec.

I have to just turn off the screen. For that purpose you are going to add SETTING_Change permission ( only available in rooted handset).

Comment: Thanks, but is there a way in normal handset?

Comment: Sorry friend, No there is nothing else. I had already spend more than 3 hours. I will appreciate if you could suggest me something

Comment: Yes, I want to. While studying at this subject, I am feeling that this answer may be in the kernel(android) area. But maybe there is a way in application area. If I find it, I will share with you. Thanks for your attention.